# Spring Boot singleton RestTemplate Accept Header keeps being appended to

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Am using Spring Boot (1.3.0.RELEASE). 
I need to call many different REST webservices using RestTemplate. 
Obviously I don't want to create a new instance of RestTemplate every single time a call is made, so I created a configuration for a single instance of RestTemplate as:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

The above is Autowired into many classes that needs to call out to external REST services... there are many! And some to GET and some do POST

```
USAGE ------------------------
ResponseEntity<String> response =
getRestTemplate().exchange(getUri(), HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

USAGE------------------------ 
getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());            
String response = getRestTemplate().getForObject(getUri(), String.class, toc);
------------------------
```

So I have noticed a problem with Accept Http Header. It seem to keep GROWING i.e. its being appended to. I am not setting any Accept headers in my code! This is what I see in the LOG.

```
     [http-nio-9080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              
: Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json,
 application/*+json, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, 
text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, 
*/*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, 
*/*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, 
*/*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*, 
*/*, */*, */*, */*, */*, */*]
```

This can grow and eventually will end up getting a 400 (BAD REQUEST)

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

So is the problem that RestTemplate is declared as singleton bean instance? I.e. Because many webservices can be called the same RestTemplate is used hence Accept Header keeps growing?

Can someone please help me out what do I need do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `@Bean` method returns a singleton, you always get the same `RestTemplate` instance when you call that method (you don't get a new one each time).

In your usage section, it seems you're adding the `StringHttpMessageConverter` every time you're using this REST template. Adding this message converter over and over again is probably why it's adding new Accept headers.

Move your message converters configuration into your `@Bean` method and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Brain thanks. Yes you are right the StringHttpMessageConverter was being appended. I removed it and all is working now, I don't see Accept header increasing. Also if anyone ever needs to set Headers on RestTemplate once and for all please take a look at http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-send-an-http-header-with-every-request-with-spring-resttemplate.

Comment: If you use Spring Boot you can create the RestTemplate bean the following way:       `@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }` Therefore you can also configure it.

Comment: @Brain, Would you able to get exact alternative for method or example code ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the request headers in your code? Something on the following lines

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(getUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Sai, Thanks for the reply. Yes, I did do that where ever I make use of the restTemplate.exchange() method but how then would I set headers on call to getRestTemplate().getForObject()? And also there must be a way to set the headers (e.g. Accept) once and for all as this is a singleton. Can this be done?