# Spring RestTemplate forming Invalid Header

Tags: tcpdump, rest-client, spring-rest

In my application for REST call following code is there:

ResponseEntity< String > entity = restTemplate.exchange( uri,
                    method, httpEntity, String.class );

The uri is proper, method is HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity is null.

On taking TCP Dump following info I got:
E..E.%@...Pc
.A.
.A|...Pt|YX...u.....a.....
c+.t$Je.GET /{uri} HTTP/1.1

05:57:34.986440 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 37158, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 8244)
   {hostname} > {targetIp}: Flags [P.], seq 274:8466, ack 1, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 1663813748 ecr 608855467], length 8192
E. 4.&@...1s
.A.
.A|...Pt|Zi...u.....P.....

c+.t$Je.Accept: text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, text/plain, te

05:57:34.986451 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 37159, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 658)

It seems the text/plain is getting appending after sometime and grows from single occurrence to multiple times till Accept: header length limits

Jar: spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar

I am getting 400 status on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

got the solution for my problem. It was something similar to 
[Spring Boot singleton RestTemplate Accept Header keeps being appended to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067517/spring-boot-singleton-resttemplate-accept-header-keeps-being-appended-to)

At some other place following code was there
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

where restTemplate was autowired and thus header was getting corrupted.